# Porting C library to UEFI

Tags: c, uefi

I have VC++ solution with two projects; a console application and a pure C library. The console project builds and links the C library statically.

At the moment I have the Tianocore environment set up in Ubuntu according to [Tianocore Quickstart](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/SourceForge-to-Github-Quick-Start).

How do easiest replicate my console application in UEFI? 

Could I e.g. use the HelloWorld UEFI example application to host and build my C library in a similar manner as in my console project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can built your C library in uefi environment as long as your library is not calling any functions based on OS API.

And EDK2 has provided a StdLib package where you can find some standard C libraries to help you build your C program.

Comment: Does the static lib need to have an .inf file? How should that look and how do I include it in the "main application"?

Comment: yes, .inf is used to describe a library or a driver, it tells the builder how to make this library or driver. I recommend you to have a quick view at [EDKII specs](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/EDK%20II%20Specifications) first. And after you can understand what .dsc, .dec, .inf are, then read the samples in AppPkg (small applications) and MdePkg (uefi libraries).

Comment: Do you have a small example of an application and a library, where the library is consumed by the application? Having that as a reference would solve my problem.

Comment: @TimHansson There're a couple of application samples in AppPkg and they all consuming libraries.